# what will be the Xpath for this input tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
\<div class="css-1dbjc4n r-19m6qjp r-z2wwpe r-1loqt21 r-1x0uki6 r-1e081e0 r-1f1sjgu r-ah5dr5 r-1otgn73" data-focusable="true" tabindex="0" data-testid="login-submit-btn"\>\<div class="css-76zvg2 r-jwli3a r-n6v787 r-1kfrs79 r-q4m81j" dir="auto" style="font-family: inherit;"\>Log In\</div\>\<div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1niwhzg r-1p0dtai r-1d2f490 r-1udh08x r-u8s1d r-zchlnj r-ipm5af" style="border-radius: 0px;"\>\</div\>\</div\>

\<div class="css-76zvg2 r-jwli3a r-n6v787 r-1kfrs79 r-q4m81j" dir="auto" style="font-family: inherit;"\>Log In\</div\>

\<div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1niwhzg r-1p0dtai r-1d2f490 r-1udh08x r-u8s1d r-zchlnj r-ipm5af" style="border-radius: 0px;"\>\</div\>
```

the above code is for this login button I need xpath for this particular button to click

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elHy5.png)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                "//div[@class='css-1dbjc4n r-19m6qjp r-z2wwpe r-1loqt21 r-1x0uki6 r-1e081e0 r-1f1sjgu r-ah5dr5 r-1otgn73']//div[@dir='auto'"))
                .click();
```

Comment: Can you share the URL of the app if it is public?

Comment: the login page https://www.spicejet.com/ and in that login button

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to click on the <kbd>LOGIN</kbd> button:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-testid='login-cta']")).click();
```

Full code for your reference:

```
driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
// Below line clicks the first login button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Login']")).click();
        
// below line clicks the second LOGIN button
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-testid='login-cta']")).click();
```

Imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import java.time.Duration;
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent div contains a data-testid attribute, which is usually unique (it's added for automation testers to easily find the element, and in our case it is unique). So you could easily use something like **//div[@data-testid="login-cta"]**.

If you want to locate the inside divs, you can use the above mentioned xpath and just add /div[1] or /div[2] to it. E.g.: **//div[@data-testid="login-cta"]/div[1]**